# AspectJ - compile time - Weave types int JDK classes

Tags: aop, java, aspectj, code-injection

I need to add fields into JDK Classes. e.g java.lang.String

First I tried:

```
declare parents: ( * && !java.lang.Object ) implements VistaInt;
public String[] VistaInt.abc;
```

this however doesn't work.

It throws a warning

```
this affected type is not exposed to the weaver:
org.aspectj.lang.Signature [Xlint:typeNotExposedToWeaver]
```

So I researched it on internet and find out, that it is harder as it seems to be and
AspectJ doesn't support intrumenting JDK classes directly says here:

http://www.inf.usi.ch/faculty/binder/documents/pppj08.pdf

But there is proposed something callse FERRARI framework, tool for AspectJ that should allow injecting JDK classes.

So I kept searching for it and get here:

http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/aspectj-dev/msg02520.html

But none of these links work and I was not able to find any other source, or tool or anything that would help me.

Do you have any idea, where to find this library, or how to inject java JDK types??

Thank you!

Comment: I assume you're weaving the java library jar...? Can you give the command line call you're using.

Comment: I think I am weaving .jar, but as far as I know, compile-time weaver that is used in default should have no problem with it. I am not sure what you mean by "the command line call". I am using Eclipse with AspectJ plugin.

Comment: Ah okay. In Eclipse you are weaving your own code not the JDK code. To extend JDK classes you will need to weave the rt.jar file that Eclipse uses. I don't have time now but if nobody has answered this by tomorrow I can post some detailed instructions on how to do this.

Comment: you are right!, first time I misunderstood your question. I would be  happy for any advice!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you need to locate the rt.jar that your Eclipse project is using. This is most likely the default for your machine but to check you can right-click on the JRE system library icon in your project, click on Properties and Installed JREs. The rt.jar file is under lib.

Once you have it you will need to weave it from the command line (you might need to download separate ajc compiler). Say you want to weave MyAspect.aj you would run

```
ajc -inpath rt.jar MyAspect.aj -outjar newrt.jar
```

You then need to make sure that your code uses this library by putting newrt.jar on the bootclasspath ahead of rt.jar. Running from the command line you do this

```
java -Xbootclasspath/<path to newrt.jar> MyApplication
```

In Eclsipse you add `-Xbootclasspath/<path to newrt.jar>` to the Run configuration.

However, I would not recommend modifying `java.lang.String` as JVMs often treat this class specially. But you can give it a go if you want :)

**Note**

I believe that the FERRARI framework that you refer to is for LTW (Load Time Weaving) and this discussion has been for a CTW (Compile Time Weaving) solution. If you want to do LTW then you're going to have difficulties as custom class loaders can't load `java.*` classes so you can't weave these at load time. Your link suggests that people have attempted a workaround but I don't know anything about this.

Comment: Thank you very much! That is exactly what I needed...I would do LWT if it was necessary, but though it is easier trough compile-time. just could not find anything relevant. Btw, It is kind of experiment at uni, I wouldn't really mess up with rt.jar classes.-and its fun too :)

Comment: Actually what I usually do when weaving JDK classes is to just create a small JAR of woven JDK classes instead of a big one and then prepend that JAR to the boot classpath, thus shadowing the original classes. This is kind of minimally invasive.